# How to expose REST service with Apache Camel?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, integration

When I try to expose the REST service using Apache Camel everything seems to be fine, but when I try to retrieve the data from the url it doesn't connect. The thing I noticed in debug logs is that the route destination is actually null. Here are the logs for route startup:

> 17:54:20.617 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Route: route1 started and consuming from: activemq://queue:MATERIALS_ENRICHED
> 17:54:20.620 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Route: route2 >>> Route[activemq://topic:MATERIALS_FILTERED -> null]
> 17:54:20.621 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Starting consumer (order: 1001) on route: route2

I have no idea why it is as it is, i thought it was worth noticing. Here's the code I wrote:

```
public class RestExposer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");

    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addComponent("activemq", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
            JaxbDataFormat xmlDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext);

            restConfiguration()
                    .producerComponent("undertow")
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port("8080")
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

            from("activemq:queue:MATERIALS_ENRICHED")
                    .unmarshal(xmlDataFormat)
                    .filter(simple("${body.type} in 'A1,A2,A3'"))
                    .marshal().json()
                    .to("activemq:topic:MATERIALS_FILTERED");

            from("activemq:topic:MATERIALS_FILTERED")
                    .to("rest:get:materials");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    }
}
```

And the pom.xml file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>
> <groupId>org.example</groupId>
> <artifactId>Packages</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>
> <properties>
>     <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
> </properties>
>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
>         <version>2.8.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>         <version>8.0.28</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
>         <version>2.17.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId >
>         <version>2.17.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
>         <version>5.16.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
>         <version>5.16.4</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-jaxb-starter</artifactId>
>         <version>2.25.4</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
>         <version>3.15.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>         <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
>         <version>5.16.4</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
>         <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
>         <version>2.13.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
>         <version>1.7</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-undertow</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
>         <version>3.1.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
>         <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
>         <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-openapi-java</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-undertow</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>         <artifactId>camel-support</artifactId>
>         <version>3.16.0</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies> </project>
> ```

I didn't attach full debug logs because it's very long, but let me know shall I do it. Please help me.

EDIT:
I've changed the routes to match the REST DSL Camel documentation, now I can curl to the adddress, but it just waits for 20 seconds and then I get ExchangeTimeOutException. Here's the code of those routes:

```java
restConfiguration()
    .component("undertow")
    .host("localhost")
    .port(8080)
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

rest("/api/")
    .get("materials").consumes("application/json").to("direct:materials");

from("activemq:queue:MATERIALS_ENRICHED")
    .unmarshal(xmlDataFormat)
    .filter(simple("${body.type} in 'A1,A2,A3'"))
    .marshal().json()
    .to("activemq:topic:MATERIALS_FILTERED");

from("direct:materials")
    .to("activemq:topic:MATERIALS_FILTERED");
```

I know I've changed the url from /materials to /api/materials, it doesn't matter at this point.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do. Please note that you don't expose any rest endpoint with your current code. Please have a look to Rest DSL https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html for a better understanding

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get the data from MATERIALS_FILTERED topic and expose them to localhost:8080/materials endpoint.

Comment: A topic is not a database, so for me what you are trying to do, doesn't really make sense. If you want to expose the data of a topic, you need first to store it somewhere

Comment: I know, but that's the task I got. I've got those data stored, there's an other class that retrieves them and does some stuff to it. Now I've got to expose those data from the topic to REST, that's my internship project to learn Camel